Swagger generating request string[] headers incorrectly?
Im having an interesting issue in the generated swagger document concerning headers.
In this case the header permissions is a string[]

In the request object received in the controller instead of the expected: ["1", "2", "3"], I am getting: ["1&permissions=2&permissions=3"].
From reading the swagger documentation the format for headers should always be simple, yet looking at the json document generated by Nswag it appears to be sending it as a form?
 {
    "name": "permissions",
    "in": "header",
    "style": "form",
    "explode": true,
    "schema": {
      "type": "array",
      "nullable": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "x-position": 2
  },

Here is how it is defined in the C# controller:
[FromHeader] IEnumerable<string> permissions

Versions used:
"x-generator": "NSwag v14.0.3.0 (NJsonSchema v11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))"
"openapi": "3.0.0",
.NET 8
If anyone knows what I am doing wrong or if this is an actual bug on Nswag's side please let me know! Many thanks in advance.

I highly doubt that ASP.NET Core will be able to bind  ["1", "2", "3"] as array/enumerable of strings. Use what NSwag does.

So to clarify it works absolutely fine when passing in header permissions like this:
-H 'permissions: 1,2,3'

But the swagger generated request passes in the header like this:
-H 'permissions: 1&permissions=2&permissions=3'

Looks like an issue with the library (NSwag or Swashbuckle?) that generates an OpenAPI definition from your code. As you've correctly noted, it should generate header parameters with style: simple (instead of style: form) as this is the only style that header parameters actually support. Alternatively, you might need to manually add annotations that would produce style: simple.
